# Change selected sections

Tags: vba, ms-word

[image]My problem is that depenting on in which direction I select the text, from page 5-10 or from page 10-5, I get different results. The code below starts from the active page.

```
Sub setOdd()
Call editBrake("odd")
End Sub

Sub editBrake(typ As String)
Dim iSec As Long, iSecs As Long, iSecTot As Long, i As Long, s As Section

iSec = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber)
iSecs = iSec + Selection.Sections.Count - 1
iSecTot = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count

If iSecTot >= iSec Then
    For i = iSec To iSecs
        Set s = ActiveDocument.Sections(i)
        If typ = "new" Then
            s.PageSetup.SectionStart = wdSectionNewPage
        ElseIf typ = "odd" Then
            s.PageSetup.SectionStart = wdSectionOddPage
        ElseIf typ = "even" Then
            s.PageSetup.SectionStart = wdSectionEvenPage
        End If
    Next i
ElseIf iSecTot = 1 Then
    MsgBox "There is no section breaks in document", vbInformation, "Change section breaks"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep it simple by looping through the selected sections.

```
Sub editBreak(typ As String)
    Dim s As Section

    If ActiveDocument.Sections.Count > 1 Then
        For Each s In Selection.Sections
            If typ = "new" Then
                s.PageSetup.SectionStart = wdSectionNewPage
            ElseIf typ = "odd" Then
                s.PageSetup.SectionStart = wdSectionOddPage
            ElseIf typ = "even" Then
                s.PageSetup.SectionStart = wdSectionEvenPage
            End If
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "There are no section breaks in document", vbInformation, "Change section breaks"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Timothy, If I try your code and select some text, a section break and then some text, both the first and the second section break changes. Let me add a picture so that you can see.

Comment: @Loveb - of course it does, because your selection spans two sections

Comment: That's what I want to do. To be able to select from page 2-4 or from 4-2 and change the selected section breaks. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Loveb - then place your cursor in the first section you want to change and select up to the last one you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Timothy Rylatt the following code works. (I also have a code for `Selection.Sections.Count = 1`)

```
Sub editBrake(typ As String)
Dim s As Section
Dim i As Integer
Dim skipFirst As Boolean
i = 1
If Selection.Sections.Count > 1 Then
    skipFirst = True
    For Each s In Selection.Sections
        If skipFirst Then
            skipFirst = False
        Else
            If typ = "new" Then
                s.PageSetup.SectionStart = wdSectionNewPage
            ElseIf typ = "odd" Then
                s.PageSetup.SectionStart = wdSectionOddPage
            ElseIf typ = "even" Then
                s.PageSetup.SectionStart = wdSectionEvenPage
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
Else
    MsgBox "There are no section breaks in document", vbInformation, "Change section breaks"
End If
End Sub
```